# Writing NaN values to MongoDB output - Pentaho

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I have some null (empty / missing) values in some fields in my psql database. I want to read this data and write to a MongoDB output, but I want those null values to be translated to NaN in mongo. Can you help me as to what I should use to do this ?

I've tried using 'If field value is null' step but that doesnt seem to do what i want it to ... Thanks

Comment: What did you try with `if field value is null`, and what does it do that is not what you want? It sounds like this should be the correct way to solve this.

Comment: I checked the 'Select value type' option, put 'Type' as Number, and put 'Replace by value' as 'NaN' ... but that doesnt work as it is taking Nan as string and hence cannot replace that in an integer field ..
One of my motives is to replace emty integer fields with NaN, hence the above was done

Comment: Yes, so the real question is how do I put a NaN in mongo from PDI, and has actually nothing to do with the `null` values?

Comment: Well yes. It has nothing to d with `null` actually ... I just mentioned that to give a complete description of the problem, because it is the `null` values that Im trying to translate to NaN's. Anyways I have actually found a solution to this problem. I've posted it as an answer in case for others who have a similar query.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this. Use the **Modified Java script value** step, and in the script, you can set the field value to anything you want. In my case, I would put this in the javascript code :

```
if (fieldname == null ){
    fieldname = NaN
}
```